# Need some explaination about history.js by Benjamin

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, pushstate, history.js

Currently I am facing the ajax URL change problem.

Let's say I have an ajax call, when user click on the div and the div will expand and ajax get data from db but the url doesn't change.

Then I found about html5 history api at firefox website. At the bottom of the page recommend [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) to overcome cross-browser issues.

But then, I found [jquery-history.js](https://github.com/balupton/jquery-history) and [jquery-ajaxy](http://balupton.github.com/jquery-ajaxy/demo/) , Omg, why there is so much version?

Any suggestion which I have to use? 
What I want is all my ajax call

- does provide url change
- back / next browser button
- Using HTML5 api
- Don't Care about old browser
- Don't Care IE
- It is real no fully page reload but not just fake it.

And I am using jquery.

Comment: Please, I need the answer to learn this urgent!!

Comment: do you want to do hash changes or full URL changes? for full URL changes for modern browsers, I suggest just using `window.history` itself since it's not that difficult. I tried using `history.js` but it made things more difficult, plus it's not actively maintained. I would just make sure to block browsers that don't support it via Modernizr. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: @JonathanOng  I don't want to use hash changes as my target is modern browsers. Yes, i found the window.history at [mozilla site] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), scroll to the very bottom. It recommend to use history.js to overcome cross-browser. And yes, i want it to work in cross-browser.

Comment: there are very little cross-compatibility issues. they are listed in the history.js wiki and mdn page.

Comment: Ok, then I will just using the window.history. Thanks

Comment: Yeah. The only issues I think are replace state and title

Answer (score 1):

If you [care about URLs](http://danwebb.net/2011/5/28/it-is-about-the-hashbangs) and noscript clients then just create a non-AJAX site and enhance it with [jquery-pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax).

If you don't care then just use hashes.

Comment: I don't care noscript clients, which mean my site is always require js to run. I found pjax as well but it is like fake page reload?

Am i right?  I am new in this.